# Alternating Generations GA? To keep evaluators running

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm

**What I want?**
I Want to be able to generate population for generation N+2, from ranked population of generation N; while the generation N+1 is still in evaluation. Once the generation N+1 finishes evaluation it will be used to generate generation N+3 (and at that point generation N+2 evaluation will be already running).

**Why do I want that?**
To better utilize computing resources. My evaluation threads can then run continuously with minimum synchronization and waiting. For a fast evaluation and small generations a single generation can be finished in a very quick time and evaluation thread would then need to wait for next generation; instead it can already work on something else.

**Alternative thought**
Alternative is to have 2 independent GAs run and generate generations while taking rounds in access to evaluation threads.
This is utilizing resources better, however it's obviously not allways what we want to do (digging two holes instead digging a single hole doesn't allways mean I can find oil faster)

Comment: Looks like parallel runs with migration can be an interresting way (described e.g. [here](http://www.pohlheim.com/Papers/mpga_gal95/gal2_5.html))

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @werediver Questions remains the same - how can I skip generations during population creation. It seems that there might be one way using the migration; but I'm still interrested should there be any other - more recommendable approaches. I bet I'm not the first one trying something like that

Comment: If the question is "how to skip" then the answer is quite straightforward, skip generations and merge the results however is suitable according to your requirements. It seems, though, that you're asking about some existing / described approaches. So, my advice is to make it crystal clear what exactly you're asking. Right now this question does not look like a question to me (unclear what you're asking), unfortunately.

Comment: What's exactly meant by 'merge the results'? Do you mean 2 independent GAs and chossing the best results at the end of run of both?

Comment: You have plenty of options; it depends on your needs and preferences. We can come up with some example strategy, but you seem to have enough ideas, so this hardly is your problem.